# Show difference between pictures as vectors

Tags: c#, .net, image, aforge

I want to write in C# using some graphic library app that will show difference between two pictures as a map of vectors, which will show movement of points.

Something like this is implemented for matlab and is called PIVlab and as a example:
difference between

[image]

and

[image]

is represented by first image in

[image]

I would be very happy to write something similiar in .NET using for instance AForge. Can you help?

Comment: Have you looked at OpenCV? http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to find the [Optical flow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_flow). Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803061/how-to-implement-optical-flow-tracker) for a C# + emguCV implementation of an optical flow tracker.

Answer (score 0):

An interesting question, are the dots always in view ? 
Or is the image not that stable like camera noice.

Is the motion slow or fast > i mean is a pixel within reach between frames ?

Do the pixels move like in a single large group, for example tracking stars
Or do the pixels move more like groups of clouds or birds in the air ?
Or do the pixels move like flees each in various directions ?
Might there be some general suspected movement (like camera driving?)

Could you update your question with such info in your original question.

Because that differs a lot, in most cases its about tracking a near neighbor one might write an outspiraling pixel check for each pixel (or just for easy programming from small rectangle to large rectangle
That might not be fast dough its best for the flees example